# Set plotly tooltip text color the same as the hovered pixel of an heatmap

Tags: python, plotly, hover, heatmap, plotly-python

I'm plotting a quite large heatmap using plotly. I would like to have access to the color of each pixel in the hoverlabel to color a symbol accordingly. Here is what I managed to do so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.colors as pc

# generate image
size = 5
img = np.random.random((size, size+2))
# manually generate colors
min_value, max_value = img.min(), img.max()
cmap = pc.sequential.Jet
colors = pc.sample_colorscale(cmap, (img.ravel() - min_value) / (max_value - min_value), colortype="tuple")
# convert to HTML hex color codes and reshape to image shape
colors = np.reshape([f'#{int(c[0]*255):02x}{int(c[1]*255):02x}{int(c[2]*255):02x}' for c in colors], img.shape)
# plot heatmap
fig = go.Figure(
    go.Heatmap(
        z=img,
        colorscale=cmap,
        customdata=colors,
        hovertemplate='Value %{z} with color <span style="color:%{customdata};">⬤</span>',
        name=''
    )
)
fig.show('browser')
```

[image: heatmap]

However, this method uses `customdata` to pass the array of colors, which is not very convenient as it doubles the final size of the resulting HTML (that can be over 100 or 200 MB).

We know that at some point, the colors are computed by plotly. I would like to know if there is a way to access this in the hoverlabel without having to manually pass them as `customdata` as this is redundant (something like `%{color}` for example but this does not exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update: Only color the ⬤, not the entire string

[image]

It's pretty difficult to see with the darker colors. However, if you only wanted to change the ⬤, this will work.

Instead of `relayout`, this is a `restyle`. (It changes a trace, not the layout.)

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Heatmap(z = img, hovertemplate = 'Value %{z} with color <span style="color:red;">⬤</span>'))

pio.write_html(fig, 'index.html', auto_open = True, include_mathjax = 'cdn', include_plotlyjs = 'cdn',
                full_html = True, div_id = 'myDiv',                           # this id is used in the JS
                post_script = "setTimeout(function() {" +
                                "el = document.getElementById('myDiv');" +
                                "el.on('plotly_hover', function(d) {" +
                                  "cols = el.calcdata[0][0].trace.colorscale; /* get colors by value */" +
                                  "vals = Object.values(cols);" +
                                  "z = d.points[0].z;                         /* collect current hover point data */"  +
                                  "i = [];                                    /* reset i in each event */" +
                                  "vals.forEach((n, index) => {" +
                                    "if(n[0] > z){" +
                                      "i.push(index);                         /* find the right color */" +
                                    "}                                        /* end if */"  +
                                  "});                                        /* end forEach */" +
                                  "/* 2 values for each key, the lower range of z and color */" +
                                  "newC = Object.values(cols)[i[0]][1];       /* extract hex value for color */" +
                                  "labf = d.points[0].fullData.hovertemplate; /* get object to update */" +
                                  "old = labf.match(/(?<=(color:)(.*)(?=;))/)[2];  /* capture color to replace next */"
                                  "labf = labf.replace(old, newC);" +
                                  "Plotly.restyle(el, {'hovertemplate': labf}, d.curveNumber); /* make the change */" +
                                "});" +
                               "});")
```

The JS without the quotes & '+':

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    el = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    cols = el.calcdata[0][0].trace.colorscale;         /* get colors by value */
    vals = Object.values(cols);
    el.on('plotly_hover', function(d) {
        z = d.points[0].z;                   /* collect current hover point data */
        i = [];                                         /* reset i in each event */
        vals.forEach((n, index) => {
            if(n[0] > z){
                i.push(index);                          /* find the right color */
            }                                           /* end if */
        })                                              /* end forEach */
            /* 2 values for each key, the lower range of z and color */
        newC = Object.values(cols)[i[0]][1];            /* extract hex value for color */
        labf = d.points[0].fullData.hovertemplate;      /* get object to update */
        old = labf.match(/(?<=(color:)(.*)(?=;))/)[2];  /* capture color to replace next */
        labf = labf.replace(old, newC);
        Plotly.restyle(el, {'hovertemplate': labf}, d.curveNumber) /* make the change */
    });
});
```

###---- original answer -----

I think this is what you're looking for.

[image]

[image]

You mentioned this as an eternal HTML file, and in order to do this, you'll need to at least create the external file.
I used `plotly.io`'s `write_html` so that I could append Javascript with the argument `post_script`. The file size is 10kb. I don't know what you're using in your file (i.e., data, options, all that), but you may want to look at the arguments I've used in `pio.write_html()`.

You also mentioned that you did not want to designate colors. I did not designate any specific colors when creating the plot.

I used `np.random.seed(0)` so that you could reproduce my example, as well.

I used comments in my Javascript so that if you wanted to understand what was happening, you could. If you have any questions, let me know.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import numpy as np

# generate image
size = 5
np.random.seed(0)           # for consistency
img = np.random.random((size, size+2))
# manually generate colors
min_value, max_value = img.min(), img.max()

fig = go.Figure(go.Heatmap(z = img, hovertemplate = 'Value %{z} with color ⬤'))

# fig.show()

pio.write_html(fig, 'index.html', auto_open = True, include_mathjax = 'cdn', include_plotlyjs = 'cdn',
                full_html = True, div_id = 'myDiv',       # this id is used in the JS
                post_script = "setTimeout(function() {" +
                                "el = document.getElementById('myDiv');" +
                                "el.on('plotly_hover', function(d) {" +
                                  "cols = el.calcdata[0][0].trace.colorscale; /* get colors by value */" +
                                  "vals = Object.values(cols);" +
                                  "z = d.points[0].z;  /* collect current hover point data */"  +
                                  "i = [];             /* reset i in each event */" +
                                  "vals.forEach((n, index) => {" +
                                    "if(n[0] > z){" +
                                      "i.push(index);  /* find the right color */" +
                                    "} /* end if */"  +
                                  "});    /* end forEach */" +
                                  "/* 2 values for each key, the lower range of z and color */" +
                                  "newC = Object.values(cols)[i[0]][1];    /* extract hex value for color */" +
                                  "labf = d.points[0].fullData.hoverlabel; /* get object to update */" +
                                  "labf.font.color = newC;                 /* set font color */" +
                                  "if(z < .5) {            /* find contrasting background color */" + 
                                    "bgc = Object.values(cols)[7][1] /* orangish yellow background for dark colors */" +
                                    "} else {" +
                                    "bgc = Object.values(cols)[1][1] /* dark blueish-purple background for light colors */" +
                                  "}" +
                                  "labf.bgcolor = bgc; /* set bgcolor based on conditions */" + 
                                  "Plotly.relayout(el, {'hoverlabel': labf}, d.curveNumber) /* make the change */" +
                                "});" +
                               "});")
```

The JS without the quotes & '+':

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    el = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    cols = el.calcdata[0][0].trace.colorscale; /* get colors by value */
    vals = Object.values(cols);
    el.on('plotly_hover', function(d) {
        z = d.points[0].z;  /* collect current hover point data */
        i = [];             /* reset i in each event */
        vals.forEach((n, index) => {
            if(n[0] > z){
                i.push(index);  /* find the right color */
            } /* end if */
        });    /* end forEach */
            /* 2 values for each key, the lower range of z and color */
        newC = Object.values(cols)[i[0]][1];    /* extract hex value for color */
        labf = d.points[0].fullData.hoverlabel; /* get object to update */
        labf.font.color = newC;                 /* set font color */
        if(z < .5) {            /* find contrasting background color */
            bgc = Object.values(cols)[7][1]; /* orangish yellow background for dark colors */
        } else {
            bgc = Object.values(cols)[1][1]; /* dark blueish-purple background for light colors */
        }
        labf.bgcolor = bgc; /* set bgcolor based on conditions */
        Plotly.relayout(el, {'hoverlabel': labf}, d.curveNumber) /* make the change */
    });
});
```

Comment: Good job ! It would be nice to have the post_script as a separate code snippet (lang-js, for proper syntax highlighting), you might also prefer to wrap it in a multiline string instead of catenating multiple strings. Note that you can also pass a post_script to the .show() method (provided that the specified renderer outputs html), ie. `fig.show(renderer='browser', post_script=[js_str])`.

Comment: That's all very useful information! Thank you. I tend to code a lot more in R, where I can just write the JS, no messing with iterations of quotes and plusses, but I can still use indenting to make sure that it's all nested correctly... or better yet, RMarkdown, where I can just annotate what language it is and see the syntax highlighting...I'm an 'anti-notebook-type-person,' so finding ways around that seems to be a bit annoying. I will DEFINITELY use the information you've provided!

Comment: Wow this looks absolutly amazing! I wasn't aware of the `post_script` argument. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar at all with js (and even less with plotly.js) so I would not have been able to figure out something like that by myself! By any chance, do you know if there would be a simple way to color only the circle as I did in my example? (and let the rest of the text with the default color) I guess it could be possible to explore the `labf` variable to extract the text and add a `span` tag with the color around the circle, but I have no idea how to debug/test/explore js objects

Comment: I've updated my answer. It now contains solutions to both color the entire string and to change the color of the ⬤. It's really hard to see the ⬤ with the darker colors though. It may still be better to do some sort of combination of the two. Perhaps just swap the text color and background color for the darker colors? (Black-ish text on a white-ish background for like dark purple, for example?)

Comment: I'm sorry I somehow missed your last answer. This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! I don't need to tweak the background color because I only have bright colors, this random matrix was just for the example ;)